# Align bootstrap button into one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have web layout with 3 buttons inside the layout. I want to align thats 3 button into one line horizontally but I still doesn't get the way.

This is the layout screenshoot :

[image]

And this is my code :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <legend style="text-transform: uppercase;">Header 1</legend>
                                <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/uploads/cms/home_pages/<?=$page_data->register_image?>">
                                <p class="mt15"><?=$page_data->register_text?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a href="<?=site_url()?>register_modal" class="ajax">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning">REGISTER</button>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <legend style="text-transform: uppercase;">Header 2</legend>
                                <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/uploads/cms/home_pages/<?=$page_data->login_image?>">
                                <p class="mt15"><?=$page_data->login_text?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <a href="<?=site_url()?>login_modal" class="ajax">
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning">LOGIN</button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <legend style="text-transform: uppercase;">Header 3</legend>
                                <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/uploads/cms/home_pages/<?=$page_data->find_image?>">
                                <p class="mt15"><?=$page_data->find_text?></p>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a href="<?=site_url()?>search_modal" class="ajax">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning">SEARCH</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hc6xcruk/

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Please post your code in jsfiddle along with the css.

Comment: The css is pure from bootstrap css @cosmoonot

Comment: k, well, you could possibly position your button row div to `bottom:0px;`. That way it's always at the bottom of the div and wouldn't depend on the content length. Make sure the height of columns are equal too, max-height maybe. @Antonio.

Comment: I suggest having a `max-height` on your description div and just do something if the character exceeds the height. like add a `read more` function.

Comment: @cosmoonot suggestion is another way.

Comment: @cosmoonot I try to use `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` and it's doesn't work

Comment: @Terence Any else suggestion ? I don't want to use `read more` because the text is not too long.

Comment: @Antonio you need to set a max-height on col-md-4 too. That way all columns are equal height.

Comment: @cosmoonot can you give some example code please

Comment: @Antonio I would, but I really need to see your current version to suggest a proper code. Kinda difficult otherwise. :/

Comment: @cosmoonot I already post my code in jsfiddle, please look at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix the height `p.mt15{ height:90px;}`

try this one https://jsfiddle.net/hc6xcruk/1/

Comment: Why you reject my changes. Even I try to improve your answer and make your code more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

how about having all the buttons in one row after a content row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"><button></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><button></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give a height to the class `mt15` or better way to add class in `<p>` tag for that section and add height CSS to it. Height should be in reference to the section has maximum content.

`<div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                 <legend style="text-transform: uppercase;">Header 1</legend>
                 <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/uploads/cms/home_pages/<?=$page_data->register_image?>">
                 <p class="mt15" style="height=70px; min-height:70px;"><?=$page_data->register_text?></p>
             </div>
</div>`

Simply I have added an inline CSS to the `<p>` tag. You can also add class and give CSS to it. That height must be in reference to the maximum content you have from all the div. As for example if you have 3 div and 2nd one have the more content then height should be according to the second div. Height must be equal for all the division i.e. for `<p>` tag

Comment: Did you add the CSS to all the <p> tag of all three div? Did you change the height according to the div having maximum content? Also,add `display:block` to the CSS.

Comment: Yes I did all of that

Answer (score 0):

Use style="max-height:170px; overflow:hidden;" for image container will solve the issue.

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="row" style="max-height:170px; overflow:hidden;">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          ....
                          <p class="mt15" style="height=70px;"><?=$page_data->register_text?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           ...........
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then set height 60 or 70 px to the class "mt15". <p class="mt15" style="height=70px;"><?=$page_data->register_text?></p>